Can we use SFTP GET command to retrieve the latest file from the directory?
I looked for a solution to retrieve the latest file from the directory and found in google in this very website.
latest_remote_file = $(ssh username@server_name 'ls -tr /path | tail -n 1')
scp -r username@server_name:/path/$latest_remote_file /my/directory

But these commands work only in the server where SSH connectivity is enabled. But, due to some security reasons, they are refusing to enable the ssh connectivity on a remote server, due to which these commands are failing. So, I want to know if the SFTP get command can perform the same function.
We need to retrieve the latest file from the directory in remote server to which we receive files everyday.
Since these commands are failing due to non enablement of ssh, I am looking for an alternative, one which I know is "get" command, can this be used to get the latest file from the remote server directory?  If so, please can some one share the syntax.
Many thanks in advance.

But I want SFTP Get command to do this job, this link points to the website I already seen. SCP is not allowed in the remote server I was mentioning. Please let me know if SFTP get command can get the latest file from the folder.

The get command cannot do it. But a combination of ls and get commands can do it, as the answer by @SanjayBharwani shows. Have you even tried it? Your question does not say that. If you have tried it, explain what's wrong about it.

Maybe you can ask the folk who run the server to create a symlink called latest which always points to the newest file for you. Then GET that.

I referred the link, that commands works well in the Unix server, but the same command is not working inside JCL due to length constraints, is there a shorter command? I even tried to shorten its length as much as possible, but the length is coming more than 80 characters, and the BPXBATCH parm doesnt accept more than 80 characters..

Well, your question never mentioned JCL until now. If you have a JCL problem, you have completely different question.

okay, the Unix file, doesn't accept more than 80 characters, as far as I observed, the characters are getting truncated in the shell script that is given to BPXBATCH utility. I thought the command would work in JCL, never imagined, I would face this issue..

Okay, thanks for all the help, my issue got fixed. Thanks again.
